# Auto pagination of set number of items (with auto scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am trying to find a jQuery script that will take list items and virtually paginate them into 9 items per page. I have seen similar scripts on Dynamic drive, but they do not auto-play.

For example: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/virtualpagination.htm

Demo #1 here is almost perfect if it auto-played with a slide or fade effect. Is there a script out there that does this? Or is it easy to modify this script?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"autoplay" as you described can be achieved with a `setInterval`.  Now I dont know the internals of that script, but something sort of like this should work.

```
// New image every 3 seconds
setInterval(function() {
  slideShowObj.next();
}, 3000);
```

Where "slideShowObject" is some object that has a next function that shows the next item.  Filling in that middle line is up to you.